# Scala Circular Map

Tags: scala

Does Scala have a Circular Map similar to how Guava EvictingQueue or Commons CircularFifoBuffer but for a map. I want to restrict the growth of the map without emtying it.

```
val MapCache = collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
```

I had a look here but did not see anything that would work. 
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html

Comment: you can easily use mentioned collections in scala code.

Comment: I could but these are not maps and using an object of key value pair means I still have to iterate the map to do a .contains.

Comment: what eviction rules you expect to be for HashMap?  There are no such thing as first or last element there... What you can use also is `WeakHashMap` which is remove elements based on GC usage.... scalaz has some kind of wrapper for it. `Memo` `weakHashMemo`

Comment: What is the use case?  Is what you want really a cache implementation?  If so i highly suggest spray-cache.

Answer (score 0):

In the base library `no`.

The beforementioned `spray cache` http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-caching/ is based on https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap, a Java Library.

Using a good Java based implementation or the small wrapper spray provides should be a good bet.

The only exception to this rule would be if you try to implement something with ScalaJs and can not use the Java Libs.